# Linq to Entities Convert Type in IQueryable

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, linq-to-entities

Using EnitityFramework 6, we create a method which takes `IQueryable` of an input type (database entity) and returns `IQueryable` of an output type.  The converter class also has a method to convert a single instance of input type to a single instance of output type.  Using the Convert method in the `.Select` lambda parameter causes a runtime exception:

> System.NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Bar Convert(Foo)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

```
internal static class FooConverter
{
    internal static IQueryable<Bar> Convert(IQueryable<Foo> foos)
    {
        return foos.Select(d => Convert(d));
    }

    internal static Bar Convert(Foo foo)
    {
        return new Bar
        {
            Id = foo.Id,
            Number = foo.Number,
            Valid = foo.Valid ?? false,
        };
    }
}
```

Research suggests that Linq to Entities cannot generate SQL from my `Convert(Foo)` method, so I did some refactoring.  If I duplicate initialization in both methods, everything works.

```
internal static class FooConverter
{
    internal static IQueryable<Bar> Convert(IQueryable<Foo> foos)
    {
        return foos
            .Select(d => new Bar
            {
                Id = foo.Id,
                Number = foo.Number,
                Valid = foo.Valid ?? false,
            )};
    }

    internal static Bar Convert(Foo foo)
    {
        return new Bar
        {
            Id = foo.Id,
            Number = foo.Number,
            Valid = foo.Valid ?? false,
        };
    }
}
```

But now I have duplicated code.  Is it possible to call `Convert(Foo)` from within `Convert(IQueryable<Foo>)` to eliminate the redundancy?

Comment: The problem is that IQueryable deals in Expressions. The query provider walks/visits the expression tree and converts everything that it knows how into SQL. But it can only translate what it knows on the surface. It does not understand how to translate any arbitrary method call into the NewExpression/MemberInitExpressions that it needs for the projection. Have Convert return an Expression and then Compile() to a delegate (and cache it) to use from non-LINQ methods if you don't want to duplicate

Comment: Thanks pinkfloyd.  I was not familiar with Expressions<TDelegate> but your comment led me in the right direction.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335710(v=vs.110).aspx